# Circuit breaker works, but no wires are connected to it in the breaker panel

Tags: electrical

On an older Pushmatic breaker box, there is a 50 amp double breaker that says main lighting. There are no wires hooked up to it in the fuse box, but when I push in to trip the breaker, all the lights go out like it is connected. How is this breaker working?

Comment: Unless you have big industrial lights, they should not be protected just by a 50 amp breaker.  Think it is mis-labeled and might be main breaker.  Does everything else go out or just the lights?  Adding a picture of box in your question can help.

Comment: This sounds like a sub-panel main breaker. Not only are you turning off your lights but everything else attached to that box.

Comment: Can you post photos of your breaker panel please, including any labeling on the inside of the door?

Answer (score 8):

### This is called a "Split-Bus" or "Rule of Six" panel.

It has two sections internally.

First is the "Main Breaker" section.  It has typically 4 or 6 *double spaces* intended for "double width" 240V/2-pole breakers.   **These are always energized; you cannot turn them off**. Do not attempt to DIY breaker replace in this area.

Your "Main Lighting" breaker sits in this Main Breaker area.

Internally, the output of the Main Lighting breaker powers the other section of the subpanel: the "Lighting Area".  This section will shut off if you turn off the "Lighting" breaker, so it is safe to change breakers here.

Pushmatic panels are **bolt-on** -- they use physical bolts to attach the breaker to the bus bar.  This makes Pushmatics [very well rated](https://www.electriciantalk.com/threads/pushmatic-panels.262570/post-5033256) because it simply cannot have the #1 problem of any other panel (bus stab/clip problems).  However, it also makes the "Main Breaker" area unserviceable without "pulling the meter" (or the modern version, call the power company and have them turn off the smart meter).  Doing anything DIY in the main-breaker area is *simply out of the question*.

### What's the deal with split-bus panels?

"We talked about electric lighting in the kitchens, but I couldn't see the point." - Lord Grantham, *Downton Abbey*

Pre-war, electric services to a home were 30A or 60A, intended mainly for lighting.  (lighting being the "killer app").   Then large electric appliances (range, dryer, water heater etc.) came along, and houses needed 100A, 150A or even 200A service to support them. **The problem was, breakers that large were industrial-tier, and were prohibitively priced**. (same problem you have today with 400A service).  So builders got permission to use multiple smaller breakers as the "main breaker", and these went to the large appliances (which are all  240V and take double breakers).

The rule said "the main breaker can't require more than 6 hand movements" i.e. "Rule of Six".

What made them safe at time of installation is that a *Load Calculation* of the appliances was done to assure it wouldn't overload the panel.  That safety is void the moment something additional is installed, which is why "Split-Bus" panels are considered dangerous today.

The danger of a split-bus panel can be eliminated by changing the electric meter out for a "Meter-Main". (which has both a meter and main breaker).  Now, the **one** main breaker protects the panel regardless of which loads you add, and allows you to shut off power to the entire panel so you can safely work on the main breaker section on a Pushmatic.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have a rule of 6 panel.
that breaker actually feeds the lower section.
When that breaker is turned off so is the lower 12 or so breakers that actually are 15 and 20 amp with the top section having that 50 possibly a 40/50 for a electric range, water heater, well pump, some like the water heater may be below but larger loads are normally in the top section with a maximum of 6 double pole slots.
One of those slots feeding the lights section.